# Integrating template with current project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a React web app that I am creating, (used create-react-web-app). I want to integrate the following template: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-react 
on the user account page however since this is an entire web app, am having difficulties doing so (there are differences in package.json, and file structures ect).

Currently, I have the basic setup with firebase and am doing the following:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        render(<UserPage user={user}>, document.getElementById("root"));
    } else {
        render(<App user={user}>, document.getElementById("root"));
    }
}
```

I want to set it up so that this template is shown on the UserPage.

I have tried to copy files over, and change the package.json to cooperate with both my current app, and the template.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what you want to accomplish?
If its working wheres the problem?

In the end the react code cann be confusing in terms of where to start the app. But in the end when you use webpack to build your app, the JSX will be replaced by native JS and therefore you just have to call `ReactDOM.render` in the JS file you want to append the element.

Comment: Essentially I end up having two perfectly working web apps, but I want them to be merged together. The main web app has a slightly different structure than the other, so i'm not sure where to put what. Also, The main web app is using a lot less (no babel or webpack). Since the admin panel is only front end I was hoping to avoid installing many packages. Ideally there would be specific files I could just put into a folder, and then render it as I already have done above. I just dont know what to put in that folder, and what additional packages I need to install ect.

Comment: The code posted above is JSX so it will be processed through `react-loader`. After building you get an `.js` file which is just js (React is a JS framework). So in the end you just need this js output file and it will work.
In your case I would recommend putting the firebase request and condition also in a react component.
So you have one single root for your react-app and everything is handled internally.

Comment: But the code above is for my main application. Are you suggesting that I should build the admin panel application and drag over that index file? I am mainly trying to add the page from the template I had shown (the entire admin panel) to the UserPage in my code. That would require copying over certain files, and npm installing certain packages (that are used for the panel). I am mainly concerned with where I should put which files in order to accomplish this.